# How to add a .NET class library to a Blazor Web Assembly PWA

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'd like to separate my business logic out of the PWA and into a class library.

I can add the reference in the usual manner, and I can then add it to my _Imports.razor file without problem

However I can't seem to be able to call it from anywhere else.

Answer's on the web include adding a razor class library, however I'm not interested in razor class library's, I want to use an actual class library

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I made a schoolboy error...

The project that I was referencing failed to compile, hence it was invisible from within the Blazor application

Visual Studio didn't show any type of build error when building from the startup project, it only showed the error when directly building the libary

Fixed the libary, recompiled, and hey presto!